# Understanding the construction, copy and destruction when inserting objects to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, stl, copy-constructor

I am trying to understand how STL handles the insertions of objects.
I understand that STL calls the constructor or copy construct from a temporary.

This is the code I am trying to understand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
      public:
      int ObjId;;
      A(int id) : ObjId(id)
      {
            cout << "Constructing object with id: " << ObjId << endl;
      }

      A(const A& objToCpy)
      {
            ObjId = objToCpy.ObjId;
            cout << "Copying object with id: " << ObjId << endl;
       }

      ~A()
      {
            cout << "Destructing object with id: " << ObjId << endl;
      }
};


int main()
{
      std::vector<A> vecOfA;

      vecOfA.push_back(A(1));

      cout << "....................." << endl << endl;

      vecOfA.push_back(A(2));

      return 0;
}
```

**This gives the following output:**

Constructing object with id: 1

Copying object with id: 1

Destructing object with id: 1

................

Constructing object with id: 2

Copying object with id: 2

Copying object with id: 1

Destructing object with id: 1

Destructing object with id: 2

................

Destructing object with id: 1

Destructing object with id: 2

I can understand the first insertion. A temporary object with ID=1 is created and it then copy constructed and inserted in to the vector. And this temporary then gets destructed.

However, I do not understand why the copied object has ID=0, and not 1.

As for the second part, I have no idea what is going on and why it is not identical to the first insertion, with the only exception of the ID being different. Why are 2 objects copy constructed, and both of them with ID=0, not 2.

Can anybody help me understand this behavior?

Comment: "I do not understand why the copied object has ID=0, and not 1." your copy constructor does not copy anything...

Comment: I prefer for the copy constructor member initialisation to be used. So  `A(const A& objToCpy) : Objid(objToCpy.Objid)
      {
           cout << "Copying object with id: " << ObjId << endl;
       }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you leave *ObjId* uninitialized, this means you got lucky that there was 0 inserted, but there also could be basically any value visible.

By typing `A(const A& other) {...}` you define your own copy constructor and that means you show how every field is copied, so you miss `ObjId = other.ObjId` statement in your constructor.

The second case happens because your vector is resizing and thus it has to copy all elements from old storage to new, bigger one, storage that will also fit new element.

Comment: You are right! When I did reserve(10), got the behavior I expected. Thank you. That means vector usually initialize to a capacity of 1?

Comment: Yes, that's initial value for this particular implementation of vector. However I'm not sure if initially that's 0 and whenever you add an element it's allocating any additional memory. But it's not cruicial here.

Comment: leaving `ObjId` uninitialized leads to undefined behaviour, there is no luck involved

Comment: actually undefined behaviour that gives you the result you expect is the worst, because you wont spot it until its too late

Answer (score 1):

> However, I do not understand why the copied object has ID=0, and not 1.

Your copy constructor leaves `ObjId` uninitialized, so the behaviour of the program is undefined when the value is accessed.

---

> As for the second part, I have no idea what is going on and why it is not identical to the first insertion, with the only exception of the ID being different. Why are 2 objects copy constructed

This is because of how the dynamic array data structure - which is what `std::vector` is - works. Arrays can not be resized. Once the internal array of vector is too small, a bigger array is created, the old elements copied (or moved) to the new array, and the old array is destroyed.

---

> That means vector usually initialize to a capacity of 1?

One experiment doesn't tell what vector *usually* does. It appears that after the first push, the capacity was indeed one in this case on your system. There is no guarantee that it will be one in other cases (such as other implementation of `std::vector`).

Comment: Thank you. My mistake. I changed the copy constructor (edited the question) but I still see multiple objects for the second insertion.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. When I reserved(), it worked.